# arduino --verify / --upload not working (command line)

Tags: command-line

I installed Arduino IDE version 2.1 on Ubuntu via apt-get. Then I typed the following command in terminal to see if the Arduino IDE compiles my sketch.

```
 arduino --verify xx.ino
```

However, this command launches the GUI IDE. Is the CLI not supported anymore, or is the cause in apt-get the package?

Comment: There's no such thing as Arduino IDE version 2.1, the most recent version is a mere 1.8.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite possible that this "version 2.1" doesn't support command line processes. I've never heard of an Arduino IDE version 2.1. My understanding is the version you get from `apt-get install arduino` is something like 2:1.0.5+dfsg2 so maybe you interpreted that as 2.1. That version is based on Arduino IDE 1.0.5, though apparently it has some non-standard modifications. Command line operation was [first added](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc#history) in Arduino IDE 1.5.2, though some additional functionalities were added in newer versions.

You should always install the official Arduino IDE downloaded from:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Comment: Thank you very much  for the clear answer! I indeed interpreted 2:1.0.5+dfsg2 as 2.1.